# Why does declaring var timer = setTimeout(etc.) automatically execute the function?

Tags: javascript

Why does declaring var timer = setTimeout(etc.) automatically execute the setTimeout() function? And how would one pass a setTimeout() function as a variable without having the setTimeout() automatically execute?

```js
var do_this = function(params){console.log("executes automatically, but function is only declared")};
var delay = 50;
var timeoutID = setTimeout(do_this(), delay) //executes automatically
```

Comment: You're *calling* `do_this()`! Parentheses are calling functions.

Answer (score -1):

Functions such as `setTimeout` require a callback-function that can be called the moment the timer expires. When you just provide a function, it is called immediately because it is never added to the callback-queue.

Thus, you should pass it a callback-function:

```
setTimeout( () => ... )
```

Comment: When you "just provide a function", how's that different from passing a "callback-function"?!

Comment: I meant the difference between `setTimeout( function() )` and setTimeout( () => function() )`

Comment: OK. But the simpler thing to do then is just  `setTimeout(function)`…